# Printing continuous in webpage

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I'm now working on a project that requires to print some labels.

I can print ONE label (which are html elements) with js "print" function, in this case user need to configure the printer once. But could I print MANY different labels but configure once?

the js printing code is:

```
function printElement(elem){
    var win = window.open();
    self.focus();
    win.document.open();
    win.document.write('<html><head> </head><body>');
    win.document.write(elem);
    win.document.write('</body></html>');
    win.document.close();
    win.print();
    win.close();
}
```

Note: the paper to print have gaps, like sticky notes, so that user can tear them one by one easily. So I cannot write all the elements on one html and print it.

Comment: Are you printing the same label multiple times? If so, you could loop `document.write(elem)` multiple times (with some padding/bordering/etc.) to produce that same effect.

Comment: No, to print the same label multiple times user can configure with "print number" in printing coniguration. I want to print MANY DIFFERENT labels and all of them are for one times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the number of labels to print, then:

```
for( var i=0; i<labelCount; i++) {
    win.document.write(elem);
}
```

In place of your current writing `elem`.

Comment: the paper to print have gaps, like sticky notes, so that user can tear them one by one easily. As a result I cannot write all the elements on one html and print it...

Comment: Sure you can, just add `margin` to their style.